# WordPress - broken images in content editor in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Website is on SSL and i have a problem with broken images in content editor in WordPress admin. If i use firebug and check url of image, image starting with https and get an error Could not load image. If i change url in firebug to http images are visible.
If I open this page normally not in WordPress admin, pages and images looks good and page have green padlock.

Is maybe a problem with domain and SSL certificate. Because SSL certificat is for blabla.com and site is currently on blabla.com/bla/

Thanks all for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the HTTPS into the .htaccess file.

To force a specific domain to use HTTPS, use the following lines of code in the .htaccess file in your website's root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

If you want to force SSL on a specific folder you can insert the code below into a .htaccess file placed in that specific folder:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: not working :( # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /new/
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: In your database, in the table wp_options, the lines "site_url" & "base_url" contain https ?

Comment: Check also your wp_config.php, you need to have this line : define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

Comment: In your database, in the table wp_options, the lines "site_url" & "base_url" contain https ? - yes

Comment: Check also your wp_config.php, you need to have this line : define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);  - yes

Comment: Can you send me the URL of your website ? I will check the SSL certificat

Comment: Thanks, it's a multi-site ?

Comment: resolved... some images have www and website don't have www. thanks all for help